# Magmi Multi-Store set attribute to "Use Default Value"

Tags: php, magento, magmi

i have used MAgmi to import my full catalog along with tons of attribute values at multiple store levels.

During the process certain attributes were set at the store level which we want to now rest to "Use Default Value".

Is it possible to set an attribute back to "Use Default Value"

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example how to set different values for different stores? Would be very kind of you, as I have problem to set different values for different stores here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30599853/update-tax-class-id-for-one-store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your attribute.
Have a look at this:
http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Magmi_Behaviour_-_empty_values

Comment: thanks. That was useful however it dosnt mention anything regarding image attributes. This is my main focus.

Comment: have you tried setting the image attribute to an empty value?

Comment: Ya, much simpler then i thought. I just set anything to blank at the store level and it reset it to default.