# update tax_class_id for one store

Tags: magento, magmi

I import products via Magmi to Magento and would like to change the tax_class_id now for some stores / store views.

For that I would love to have an extra file that just contains the attributes for the store view.

For Example:

```
sku;    store;          tax_class_id
test;   de_de,it,de_it; 6
```

As you can see, I would like to change the `tax_class_id` for the storeview de_de, it, and de_it to 6.

But when I run this file it changes the default value of `tax_class_id` to 6.  That means that `tax_class_id` for **all** stores is set to 6. Also a test like

```
sku;    store;          tax_class_id
test;   de;             1
test;   de_de,it,de_it; 6
```

does not work.

So I am not sure if I understand the documentation correctly: http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Magmi_Behaviour_-_store_column

Am I watching at the wrong thing? Can someone help?

**Edit**

Also when I set a default value and only update it for one store, the default value is the last one I updated (store is ignored)

```
sku;    store;          tax_class_id
test;   admin;          1
test;   de_de,it,de_it; 6
```

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using the "websites" column.

The developer has stated that the documentation is out of date, and the "websites" column is back in play: https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git/issues/23

I've found using this column is the best way to make changes to certain attributes in certain websites/stores.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Harshal - The link is saying that the documentation is out of date and that the "websites" column is in use.  I included the essential parts of the answer here and provided the link for reference.

This is not a link-only answer.